# CPQ - How to restrict Generating a Document unless Custom Status field is set to 'Draft'

Tags: cpq

CPQ - How to restrict Generating a Document unless Custom Status field is set to 'Draft'

In general is is possible to show alert when a Generate Document button is clicked in CPQ

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:
if you are using standard 'Generate Document' button,Create a validation rule on Quote Document.But it will come as exception on click of save on document generation page.

Option 2:
You can create a custom button 'Generate Document' which refers to custom visualforce page on click of button,you can have your custom validation in vf page.
if your quote satisfying your business logic then redirect to standard document geneartion vf page.